# How to reference an enum from another script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

So, I've been trying to access an enum class in a script called "ModulesList". I've tried the following:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ModuleIdentifier : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string CurrentSongModule;
    ModulesList moduleList = new ModulesList();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. How can I reference this enum?

Comment: Please provide the code where you define your enum. What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What kind of error do you have?

Comment: Don't think of enums like classes, think of them as numbers with names. Use them like numbers, eg ```MyEnumType variableName = MyEnumType.NamedValue;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your class `ModuleList` I'll provide an example enum because you did not state what are those enum

So let's say that your enum is in ModuleList like this

```
class ModuleList:MonoBehaviour
{

public enum YourEnum
     {
         None, SampleA, SampleB;
     }

}
```

Then this is how you will call it from your `ModuleIdentifier` script

```
class ModuleIdentifier : MonoBehaviour
{

    ModuleList ML = new ModuleList();
    if(ML.YourEnum == ML.None)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a matching enum in two scripts.
In script A i want to set it to what the enum selection is in script B

Comment: Timed out...
I followed this example to the T.
I have a matching enum in two scripts.
1:) In script A I want to set it to what the enum selection is in script B.
The 'Aenum = m_ScriptComponent.B;' gives an error that it must be cast;
I am stuck trying use types when I want variables.